# JavaScript .bind() method simple test

Tags: javascript, prototype, bind

I wanted to test JavaScript .bind() method, but I'm doing something wrong - value (passed by reference) isn't increased and still is 5...

There's my code:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.value = 5;
}

MyObject.prototype.add = function fn0() {
  return this.value++;
}

var ancestor = new MyObject();

function functionChanger(fnc, obj) {
 fnc.bind(obj);
}

functionChanger(ancestor.add, ancestor);
```

**Correct version I wanted to achieve**

```
function functionChanger(fnc) {
 fnc();
}

functionChanger(ancestor.add.bind(ancestor));
```

Comment: where is `bind` ?.Please post complete code..

Comment: inside functionChanger() {...}

Comment: Where are you calling add? Bind just creates a new method bound to an object it doesn't call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function functionChanger(fnc, obj) {
    fnc.call(obj);
}
/* or */
function functionChanger(fnc, obj) {
    fnc.apply(obj);
}
```

Note that [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a function, so you could also use (not recommended):

```
function functionChanger(fnc, obj) {
    fnc.bind(obj)();
}
```

Comment: Why would he want to call the function in a function called `functionChanger`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Because it's nonsense to create a function if you are not calling it nor storing it in a variable. Then, my guess is that cachaito wants to call the function.

Comment: I've learned from snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass and noticed first comment by Sam Minee where was solution with bind().

Answer (score 3):

`bind` **returns** a **new** function. You aren't assigning it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can also try this..**

```
function functionChanger(fnc, obj) {
    let bindfunc = fnc.bind(obj);
    bindfunc();
}
```

bind creates a new function with new context